# How Do I Get the Phone to Automatically Open My Gate for Package Delivery?

Tags: tasker, automation, ifttt, automate

The intercom dials my number and the phone needs to press '9' to open the gate (the call disconnects when it does). I want it to do this by itself any time someone uses the intercom (I can't answer when I sleep or am driving or on silent etc.).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know from my friends and relatives whom live in gated communities. It depends on how old the intercom system is. The older communities have to use the hardwired phone lines to be able to be used with the communities exterior info-com system.

However, the newer communities do have the ability to through the communities network to connect your android device to the communities info-com system.

This though is just through again my families and friends personal experience.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the intercom system. This is a question about a phone.